# How re-attache ebs volume using terraform

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I'm trying to keep AWS EBS volume as a persistent data-store, every week my AMI changes so I have to spin-up new VM in aws. At this time I'm expecting my volume to detach from the old VM and attach to a new VM without destroying the EBS volume and data.

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
  count         = var.instance_count
  ami           = lookup(var.ami,var.aws_region)
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.terraform-demo.key_name
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.main-public-1.id
//  user_data     = "${file("install_apache.sh")}"

  tags = {
    Name  = "Terraform-${count.index + 1}"
    Batch = "5AM"
  }
}



variable "instances" {
  type = map

  default = {
    "xx" = "sss-console"
    "4xx" = "sss-upload-port"
    "xxx" = "sss"
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "cmp_kms" {
  description = "ssss-ebsencrypt"
  tags        = local.all_labels
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "volumes" {
  count             = var.instance_count
  availability_zone = element(aws_instance.my_instance.*.availability_zone, count.index )
  encrypted         = true
  kms_key_id        = aws_kms_key.cmp_kms.arn
  size              = local.volume_size
  type              = local.volume_type
  iops              = local.volume_iops
//  tags              = merge(var.extra_labels, map("Name", "${var.cell}-${element(local.volume_name, count.index)}"))

  lifecycle {
//    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes = [kms_key_id, instance_id]
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volumes-attachment" {
  depends_on   = [aws_instance.my_instance, aws_ebs_volume.volumes]
  count        = var.instance_count
  device_name  = "/dev/${element(local.volume_name, count.index)}"
  volume_id    = element(aws_ebs_volume.volumes.*.id, count.index)
  instance_id  = element(aws_instance.my_instance.*.id, count.index)
  force_detach = true
}
```

ERROR on terraform apply

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on instance.tf line 71, in resource "aws_ebs_volume" "volumes":
  71:     ignore_changes = [kms_key_id, instance_id]

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"instance_id".
```

earlier the same code use to work with terraform v0.11 but it's not working with v0.12. what is the replacement for this or how can we re-attach EBS to a different machine without destroying it?

Comment: First thing to do is fix the `lifecycle` block.  The `aws_ebs_volume` resource doesn't expose an attribute called `instance_id`.  However, you've referenced this attribute in it.  Removing it might reveal the true error.

Comment: If i remove it, It won't give any error. It deletes and recreates the ebs vol when i change AMI

Answer (score 1):

As per terraform documentation, they do not expose any attribute named as `instance_id` for resource `aws_ebs_volume`.
For reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ebs_volume.html.

You can specify the `instance_id` at the time of volume attachment using resource
`aws_volume_attachment`.

You can refer the answer given in https://gitter.im/hashicorp-terraform/Lobby?at=5ab900eb2b9dfdbc3a237e36 for more information.

Comment: It's a little different, I won't ignore change even if the instance_id changes. 

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }

I just added something like this and now it's not destroying my volume every time.